# Eclipse - change background color of opening and closing tags of current tag

Tags: eclipse, configuration

I just changed my eclipse prefs for a darker theme. The only thing I cant figure is: When you select a tag in html, the background of the opening and closing tags is changed (so is the foreground color). This is the same behaviour for selecting a var in php (the background and foreground colors of similar text in the same document are also changed). Where can I change these colors? Ive looked everywhere and cant figure how to change this settings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations
```

You do have a "Matching Tags" annotations type.

[alt text http://img225.imageshack.us/img225/6986/eclipseannotationtypes.png](http://img225.imageshack.us/img225/6986/eclipseannotationtypes.png)

Comment: Yep. Thats it. I would never find that.. Thanks!