# highlight html tags (open/end) in eclipse

Tags: java, html, xml, eclipse

I want to enable highlighting of the open/end html tag when selecting the end/open with the cursor - meaning, if you have the following sample:

```
.
.
.
<div id="div1">

</div> <!-- end of div1 -->
</div>
.
.
.
```

When putting the cursor next to the open tag `div1`, I want the end tag of this div is highlighted, and when putting the cursor next to the end tag of `div1` the open tag of this `div` is highlighted.

How to enable this feature ?

Comment: I think you are looking for [this][1] solution.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720580/eclipse-change-background-color-of-opening-and-closing-tags-of-current-tag?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you have to have HTML editor which is included by default in Web Tools Platform version. In preferences you should have Web->HTML Files->Editor. The standard WTP editor does this highlighting by default.

Comment: you are right, but i couldn't find something specific for what i want

Answer (score 14):

> General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations

Then find "Matching Tags" and change the color there.